# Diferencia en usar una función con paréntesis y sin parentesis en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Cuando yo instancio o mando llamar una función, pongo paréntesis:

```
def saludo ():
    print('Hola')

saludo()      #esta es la llamada (poniendo paréntesis)
```

Pero cuando hago uso de una función en un **"command"** en mi caso especifico, como lo muestro en el siguiente fragmento de código (es de Tkinter):

```
varOpcion=IntVar()

def imprimir():
    print(varOpcion.get())

Radiobutton(root, text='Europa', variable=varOpcion, value=1, command=imprimir).pack()
```

*Notesé que la llamada a la función **imprimir** va sin parentesis.*

Pero cuando hago lo mismo de llamar a la función con paréntesis, ya no funciona de la misma manera:

```
varOpcion=IntVar()

def imprimir():
    print(varOpcion.get())

Radiobutton(root, text='Europa', variable=varOpcion, value=1, command=imprimir()).pack()
```

En una si me da un valor y en otro 0 por que no hace la misma función digamos (por tener una paréntesis y otra no)

Igual, he visto que se mandan a llamar sin paréntesis algunas veces por ejemplo en un return:

```
return validacion()
# o usando sin ():
return validacion
```

(a que se debe este uso?)
A lo que voy... por que es diferente o que uso tiene o mejor dicho...que es lo que hace cuando uso una llamada con paréntesis y otra solo poniendo el nombre de la función sin paréntesis?

Agradezco a todos por su ayuda con este tema.

Comment: La función como tal con paréntesis **()** esta siendo invocada, cuando se pasa como argumento no se necesita como tal invocarla, ya se puede hacer el llamado dentro de la función. Sino estoy mal es así y en javascript se hace de esa forma realmente no se si en python también

Comment: es *prácticamente lo mismo* al pasarlo sin paréntesis es por que la llamada se hará luego y Python permite guardar en una variable una función y luego hacer la llamada a la función desde la variable, por lo que tiene sentido pasarla sin paréntesis si se va a usar luego. ejemplo, puedes hacer `def funcion():...` luego `a = funcion` y finalmente llamarla de esta forma `a()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las diferencia es que cuando usas el parentesis, estás invocando a la función, es decir, estás ejecutandola. Una función es un `Callable` (llamable) en Python y todos los `callable` pueden ser ejecutados en Python utilizando parentesis.

Cuando no utilizas los parentesis, simplemente estás pasando la referencia de la función. Diciendolo más simple, **estás pasando una variable cualquiera**, podría ser un número, o una lista, etc. Aquí ejemplos de lo dicho:

```
def multiplicacion_3(a):
    return a * 3

variable_1 = 1234

print("Llamamos a la función:", multiplicacion_3("a"))

print("Referencia, es como una variable:", multiplicacion_3)
print("Es lo mismo que llamar a una función sin parentesis:", variable_1)
```

**Salida**

```
Llamamos a la función: aaa
Referencia, es como una variable: <function multiplicacion_3 at 0x7fd5c42290d0>
Es lo mismo que llamar a una función sin parentesis: 1234
```

Efectivamente, **si utilizamos una función sin parentesis es como una variable más**, por tanto podemos actuar como actuamos con las variables, siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior:

```
def mult_3_con_info(func, a):
    print(f"Estamos multiplicando por 3 la letra {a}")
    return func(a)

mult_3_con_info(multiplicacion_3, "z")
```

**Salida:**

```
Estamos multiplicando por 3 la letra z
'zzz'
```

Hemos creado una función que recibe dos parámetros, el primero de ellos una función que será llamada internamente, pero que es **pasada como una variable más**.

Este es el sentido de tu ejemplo,**Cuando estás usando las funciones sin parentesis, es porque esa función se está comportando como una variable** que se la pasas a otra función para que la ejecute dicha función.

Comment: muy bien, solo por aclarar...Entonces si quiero que una función, comando u evento procese una función externa sin que se ejecute, debo pasarla sin paréntesis para que mi evento o función la tome como una variable (le puedo decir que es como un parámetro de mi función principal?) y al final, cuando se ejecute la función principal internamente también haga el trabajo de la función externa?

Comment: Sí, es correcto!

Answer (score 2):

**Nota:** En primer cabe aclarar que no se nada de *TKinter* y me puedo equivocar en la forma en que este hace uso de las funciones pasadas como parámetros.

Una curiosidad de las funciones es que pueden ser *guardadas* o *almacenadas* y no me refiero a su valor o a lo que retornan, sino a la referencia de la función. No hay mucha diferencia entre hacer la llamada con o sin paréntesis `()`. Como mencionó [@Daniel M Sánchez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/57915/daniel-m-s%c3%a1nchez) en su comentario, es muy parecido a lo que hace JavaScript.

Al ponerle paréntesis a la función que pasas por parámetro no debería de funcionar tan bien o debería de dar algún error (según como lo maneje Tkinter). Al pasarle la función sin paréntesis hace que tengamos un mejor manejo de la función, pues los paréntesis indica a Python de que se trata de un objeto *callable* (o *llamable*) y dependiendo de como sea la sintaxis hará una acción determinada.

Al crear una función esta se convierte, igualmente, en un objeto (todo en Python es un objeto) y podemos almacenarlo y utilizarlo de la forma en que queramos, veamos un ejemplo *curioso*

Creamos una función de la única forma posible y que todos conocen.

```py
def saludar():
    print("Hola! soy una funcion")
```

Muy bien, y si queremos guardar su valor?, la mayoría haría algo como `func = saludar()` y esto es correcto pero ahí no se guarda la función en sí sino el resultado de esta que en este caso será `None` al no tener una sentencia `return ...` escrita.

Aquí es donde viene lo interesante, pues nosotros podemos almacenar la referencia de la función en una variable como se haría con cualquier otro dato.

```
func = saludar #no se usa parentesis
```

Si nosotros hacemos un `print(saludar)` veremos por consola lo siguiente:

```
<function saludar at 0x7f18fbc1ca70>
```

Y esto es totalmente correcto pues esta es la *función* en si, solo que nosotros aún no la hemos llamado, lo cual se hace haciendo uso de los paréntesis `()`. Pero si la función ya la tenemos *almacenada* en una variable, entonces podemos hacer la *llamada* usando la variable?, la respuesta es SI.

```py
func() #hacemos la llamada usando la variable que contiene la funcion
```

Y esto arroja como resultado lo esperado (inesperado para algunos).

```
Hola! soy una funcion
```

Pues bien tu función (o clase) `Radiobutton` recibe un parámetro llamado `command` el cual tiene que ser una función por lo que le pasas `imprimir`, desconozco lo que hará tal función pero supongamos que reacciona a un *evento*. Al ya tener almacenada la función entonces podemos usarla en cualquier momento, por ejemplo si se presiona un botón entonces se hace el llamado a tu función `imprimir`, sería algo como:

```py
#suponiendo que sea una funcion
#internamente la funcion 
def Radiobutton(root, text, variable, value, command):
    #esto me lo estoy inventando
    if root:
        command() #se hace el llamado de la funcion
```

Aunque el funcionamiento interno de la función haya sido inventado es lo que seguramente esta hace y lo mismo sería en caso sea una clase, con la diferencia que variaría según sus variables o atributos sean de instancia o no.

Muchas veces hemos usado esta *sintaxis* o forma de pasar funciones a una función o por medio de un parámetro, por ejemplo la función `max()` tiene un parámetro `key` que es una función e indica según qué se obtendrá el valor máximo.

```py
lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5,3],[4,4,4]]
maximo = max(lista, key= lambda x: x[1]) #obtenemos el máximo segun el segundo elemento
```

Una `lambda` es una función anónima cuya sintaxis es `lambda <parametros>: <expresion>` donde `x` representaría cada *sub lista* y por tal razón podemos acceder a su índice `1`. Muchas de las funciones, o métodos que usamos tienen cosas parecidas, solo que no nos ponemos a pensar detalladamente en como funcionan.

Comment: Una respuesta que dice "creo que" suguiere falta de conocimientos, inseguridad.

Comment: @CandidMoe es verdad, no conozco mucho de tkinter pero me guio de los principios.