# ¿Por que se me ejecuta la función de un Button antes de ser clickeado el mismo?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy iniciando en python con `tkinter` y me encuentro con el siguiente problema : Al ponerle una función al `command` de un `Button`, el mismo se me ejecuta antes de ser *clickeado* y no logro resolverlo. Quería saber por que es que sucede esto, ya que no encuentro motivo alguno?
mi código es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x400")

def label_1(var):
    color = StringVar(value="red")
    color.set(var)
    color_2 = color.get()
    label_2 = Label(root, text="holaaaaaa", foreground=color_2)
    label_2.pack()

boton = Button(text="hola soy un boton", command=label_1("blue"))
boton.config(width=10, height=5)
boton.pack()
```

Cuando ejecuto ese código en Visual Studio Code me sale un botón con la etiqueta `holaaaaaa` de color azul sin que yo la haya llama o sin  siquiera hacer *click*, aunque la idea es que aparezca la etiqueta pero cuando *clickeo* en el botón que cambie a otro color.
Espero haberme explicado bien. Gracias.

Comment: `command=label_1("blue")` ejecuta la función `label_1`. Como no retorna valor, `command` queda en `None`. ¿Será `command=label_1`?

Comment: al pasar la función directamente con paréntesis ya la estas llamando, la forma correcta es hacerlo sin paréntesis como indica CandidMoe

Comment: Hola Elias, mira esta respuesta para conocer la diferencia entre usar o no, parentesis: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/468751/diferencia-en-usar-una-funci%c3%b3n-con-par%c3%a9ntesis-y-sin-parentesis-en-python

Comment: Hola a todos, gracias por responder. El problema es que si la coloco dentro de command sin sus parensis ¿como le mando argumentos a esa funcion?. O sea la idea es que al presionar el boton, le mande un parametro que haga el csmbio de color al clickear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo es ejecutar la función directamente, ya que al pasarle argumentos lo tomará como código ejecutable de una vez. Lo que puedes hacer es usar lambda esta palabra nos permite hacer 'mini funciones' y eso hará que todo se comprima en ella misma, y se ejecute en el momento que tu deseas 'Al momento de dar clic'.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x400")

def label_1(var):
    color = StringVar(value="red")
    color.set(var)
    color_2 = color.get()
    label_2 = Label(root, text="holaaaaaa", foreground=color_2)
    label_2.pack()

boton = Button(text="hola soy un boton", command = lambda: label_1("blue"))
boton.config(width=10, height=5)
boton.pack()
```

Esto solo los necesitas usar cuando la función que quieres llamar necesita argumentos.

Comment: No se hace una *mini función*, una lambda es una función anónima

Comment: @Christian algunos entienden que además de conocerla como función anónima es una mini función o función reducida, ya que solo permite una línea.